# Progress indicator calculating PI to many decimal places

Tags: python, progress, pi

I have written some code in python to calculate PI to a user specified number of decimal places.  I have used the Chudnovsky algorithm with details available on Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm.

I am confident that the code is working correctly and returning the correct values for PI.  The problem is that when the user specifies a high number of decimal places (for example 10,000) he or she has to stare at a flashing cursor for a very long time before a result is displayed.  I wanted to provide the user with some sort of feedback showing the progress of the calculation. I have managed to do this but the progress indicator slows the program down so much that it is unusable.

I have done this in the following way

1. I have divided the number of decimal places requested by the user into steps of ten percent by way of a generator

   ```
   def ten_percent(places):

       for i in range(int(places/10),int(places+1),int(places/10)):
           yield i

   precision_step = ten_percent(places)
   precision_check = next(precision_step)
   ```

I then have this very clunky statement to see to how many places my PI calculation is accurate

```
    try:
        test_num = abs(round(np.log10(abs(decimal.Decimal(next_pi - 
current_pi)))))
    except:
        pass
```

Firstly I have the try and except because at a point the difference between successive PI calculations becomes so small that this returns "Infinity" instead of an integer.
The next_pi & current_pi are successive calculations or iterations.
decimal.Decimal is used because 1000's of decimal places can be involved.
abs to get a positive number;
np is NumPy and is used to get the exponent in an A times 10 to the power of exponent;
abs gives a positive number

I think the above statement is my problem and I assume the calculation of the "log10" is what takes too much time.

I then have this code

```
    if test_num >= precision_check:
        print('Calculation steps: ' + str(counter-1) + ' Approximate decimal 
places: ' + str(precision_check))
        if precision_check < places:
            precision_check = next(precision_step)
```

The variable test_num is effectively my current number of decimal places for the PI calculation.
The variable precision_check is the current ten percent step of the number of decimal places requested by the user.  (Basically I want to give feedback at ten percent, twenty percent of decimal places calculated.)
Once I provide the feedback I increment to the next ten percent value.

This feedback system works but it makes the code much much slower.  For low numbers of decimal places like 100 the code is ten times slower but as the number of decimal places increases it gets slower and slower.

Thank you

Adrian

Comment: Thank you Gregory.  I will check it out.

Comment: Followed Gregory's suggestion.  Got some feedback and then modified and improved the code.  I don't think I am at a final answer yet but I have made progress.  If you are interested you can see the discussion here:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/206326/progress-indicator-makes-pi-calculation-too-slow/206355#206355